# Parse user not updating for just one specific user

Tags: swift, xcode, parse-platform

I was wondering if anyone has seen a case where Parse User table doesn't update for a specific user. I have a pretty simple code:

```
 PFUser.current()?["TorF"] = true

    PFUser.current()?.saveInBackground(block: { (success, error) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error)

        } else {



        }
    })
```

I have checks in other places of the app regarding whether there is a current PFUser, and my database shows that the user is logged in and PFUser.current() is correctly assigned to this user. The simple operation above works for all other users except for one specific user. Has anyone encountered something like this?

Comment: try to remove the app from the device and install it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this was happening because the user had changed his password and therefore invalidated his access token. The place to check for whether the user's access token is valid is via Graph request.